# JSON parsing in SwiftUI that includes HTML Tags

Tags: json, swiftui

always failing in formatting on this site so hopefully I can get this right.

I have the following json from a standard Wordpress blog:

```
{
  "id": 1006344,
  "link": "https:\/\/sneakernews.com\/2021\/03\/08\/adidas-ultra-boost-21-424-arsenal-gv9716-release-date\/",
  "title": {
    "rendered": "424 And adidas Honor Arsenal With A Sleek Ultraboost 21"
  },
  "excerpt": {
    "rendered": "<p>Planted right on Fairfax, 424 (sometimes styled FourTwoFour) has served the LA area&#8217;s high fashion needs for the better part of the past decade. And now, for their 2021 partnerships, the imprint is giving adidas a bit of help with their new Ultraboost 21. A rather simple take on the runner, the collaboration sees the [&hellip;]<\/p>\n",
    "protected": false
  },
  "author": 1130,
  "jetpack_featured_media_url": "https:\/\/sneakernews.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/adidas-ultra-boost-21-424-arsenal-GV9716-release-date-lead.jpg",
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "https:\/\/sneakernews.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/1006344"
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "href": "https:\/\/sneakernews.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts"
      }
    ],
    "about": [
      {
        "href": "https:\/\/sneakernews.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types\/post"
      }
    ],
    "author": [
      {
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https:\/\/sneakernews.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users\/1130"
      }
    ],
    "replies": [
      {
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https:\/\/sneakernews.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/comments?post=1006344"
      }
    ],
    "version-history": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "href": "https:\/\/sneakernews.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/1006344\/revisions"
      }
    ],
    "predecessor-version": [
      {
        "id": 1006354,
        "href": "https:\/\/sneakernews.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/1006344\/revisions\/1006354"
      }
    ],
    "wp:featuredmedia": [
      {
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https:\/\/sneakernews.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media\/1006346"
      }
    ],
    "wp:attachment": [
      {
        "href": "https:\/\/sneakernews.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media?parent=1006344"
      }
    ],
    "wp:term": [
      {
        "taxonomy": "category",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https:\/\/sneakernews.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories?post=1006344"
      },
      {
        "taxonomy": "post_tag",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https:\/\/sneakernews.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/tags?post=1006344"
      }
    ],
    "curies": [
      {
        "name": "wp",
        "href": "https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}",
        "templated": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now everything seems to work in my SwiftUI I'm able to extract the data I would like but when I try display the "excerpt" & "content" via

`Text("\(data.content)" as String)`

my output displays the following:

[image: Simulator output]

I've tied the following

```
struct HTMLText: UIViewRepresentable {

   let html: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work at all,

```
SneakerNewsData.swift

import Foundation

struct SneakerNewsData:Decodable, Identifiable {
    public var id: Int
    public var link: String
    public var jetpack_featured_media_url: String
    public var title: titleData
    public var excerpt: excerptData
    public var content: contentData
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case id = "id"
           case link = "link"
           case jetpack_featured_media_url = "jetpack_featured_media_url"
           case title = "title"
           case excerpt = "excerpt"
           case content = "content"
        }
}

struct titleData: Decodable {
    var rendered: String

}

struct excerptData: Decodable {
    var rendered: String

}
struct contentData: Decodable {
    var rendered: String

}
```

```
Snippet of ContentView.swift

 VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15, content: {
                    Text("\(data.content)" as String)
                   // HTMLText(html: "\(data.content)")       
                })
                .padding()
                .padding(.bottom,lastMinY)
                .background(Color.white)
                .offset(y: scale > 0.4 ? minY : lastMinY)
                .opacity(scale != 0.4 ? 1 : 0)
            }.onAppear {getData()}
```

is there a way I can remove the ContentData(rendered: from the output and perhaps display the HTML tags that is embedded in the JSON url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're still one level too shallow. You are using `data.content`, which is of type `contentData`. What you want is `data.content.rendered`, which will be the HTML.

```
Text(data.content.rendered)
```

or

```
HTMLText(html: data.content.rendered)
```

Your `HTMLText` code already looks good, so that will work.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked a treat. Really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. By the way, it is idiomatic in Swift to capitalize type names. So, you may want to change `titleData`, `contentData`, etc to capitalized if you want to conform to that trend.